# Project-specific configuration for a Spring based web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a spring based web application having several controllers which are getting a same query parameter.
I want to use this query parameter into some of my services.
Is there any way, using some inbuilt functionality of spring framework which allows me to use this parameter everywhere without the need of actually passing it as an argument while calling each service?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible but is against the "rules" of programming with beans in Spring. The default scope of a bean is Singleton:

> Only one shared instance of a singleton bean is managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring container.

Read more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

So having a singleton bean with non final class attribute that is changed in every request, probably you will end up to having request reading the wrong values because the attributes are being changed before the actual request reads it's value.